# Trying to push a Vapor app to Heroku using CLI fails

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

I have a Vapor app that I want to push to Heroku.  I used `vapor heroku init` to initialize the Heroku project.  Now that it is on Heroku, I want to be able to push changes to Heroku using `vapor heroku push`.  But every time I run that command from the Vapor CLI, I get the following:

```
Error: spawnProcess
```

Can anyone tell me why that might be failing or perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: They're working on it (https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/issues/108 and https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/pull/110) - pushing the `heroku` branch directly works as a workaround for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue started popping up recently, and we're not sure where it came from. In the meantime, you can keep an eye on this issue:

https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/issues/108

## Workaround

The push command right now is just an alias of `git push heroku master`. Using that command will work great and solve the same problem.

```
git push heroku master
```

Let me know if you have any other problems!